# struts2 validation and prepare method related

Tags: validation, struts2, struts2-interceptors

In have a  `custprofileview` Action which show a JSP page with all details of customer and in my JSP all fields are like my

```
<s:textfield name="custprofileVO.email" value="%{custprofileVO.email}" />
<s:textfield name="custprofileVO.phone" value="%{custprofileVO.phone}" />
```

and do so on, and there is a submit button that calls Action `updatecustprofile`.

In `updatecustprofile` Action, instead of directly mapping properties I have a member variable   `private CustprofileVO custprofileVO;` 
with setter and getter.

In `CustprofileVO` Class I have fields like `email`, `phone` and all other fields with their setters and getters methods.

**Problem is**: in `updatecustprofile` Action I am implementing `Prepareable` Interface, and in implementation of `prepare()` method I have `custprofileVO.setDefaultID("Select");` and setting 4 more fields but when I run the program by clicking on submit button I get `NPE` in the very first line that is `custprofileVO.setDefaultID("Select");`

It looks like the framework is not instantiating  `CustprofileVO custprofileVO`. If I manually instantiate  `custprofileVO` just above setting of the field (by doing `custprofileVO = new CustprofileVO()` then it works.
Problem is- ideally struts2 framework should give me instance which it  is not doing, want to understand the reason.

Further if I manually set  `custprofileVO` in prepare method it works but I have also applied validation using XML where my field name is  `custprofileVO.email` ,its validation then  `custprofileVO.phone` its validation.

When I try to validate on click of submit button validation runs but on screen I see messages for all fields as data in all textboxes gets blanked out.

Why is data getting removed ?

Comment: Can't you simply post your code ? It's a pain to figure out what the code is by reading a whole page of (unformatted) sentences :| Please post ***the relevant parts of*** : 1) struts.xml 2) Action class to get a better help. Until then, I'll go with the most probable answer here: wrong stack.

Answer (score 0):

You should not instantiate by yourself an object that is coming from JSP.

To get it in the `prepare()` method, run by the `Prepare Interceptor` **before** the `Param Interceptor`, [you need to use a special stack](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/interceptors.html): **`paramsPrepareParamsStack`**

```xml
 <!-- An example of the paramsPrepareParams trick. This stack
             is exactly the same as the defaultStack, except that it
             includes one extra interceptor before the prepare interceptor:
             the params interceptor.

             This is useful for when you wish to apply parameters directly
             to an object that you wish to load externally (such as a DAO
             or database or service layer), but can't load that object
             until at least the ID parameter has been loaded. By loading
             the parameters twice, you can retrieve the object in the
             prepare() method, allowing the second params interceptor to
             apply the values on the object. -->
        <interceptor-stack name="paramsPrepareParamsStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="multiselect"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="params">
                <param name="excludeParams">^class\..*,^dojo\..*,^struts\..*,^session\..*,^request\..*,^application\..*,^servlet(Request|Response)\..*,^parameters\..*,^action:.*,^method:.*</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="params">
                <param name="excludeParams">^class\..*,^dojo\..*,^struts\..*,^session\..*,^request\..*,^application\..*,^servlet(Request|Response)\..*,^parameters\..*,^action:.*,^method:.*</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
```

Comment: does `prepare()` get called before `validate()`? or after?

Comment: Since `prepare()` is run by **Prepare** Interceptor, while `validate()` is run by the **Validation** Interceptor, it depends on how you've configured them in your stack, but in the default Stack, in the paramsPrepareParamsStack, and basically in every stack not completely messed up, `prepare()` will always run **before** `validate()`.